# Is the viewfinder absolutely essential in the Point and shoot segment

Tags: point-and-shoot, viewfinder, mirrorless

This may sound like a very amateurish question but how important is it to have viewfinder in the point and shoot segment..I saw a Sony alpha a5000 mirrorless camera which looks really good specs wise but it lacks a viewfinder.Should i go for that or the Panasonic Lumix DMC-ZS50
PS:I know im comparing a mirrorless and a standard point and shoot cam here but I need help

Comment: It's a very subjective question. I wouldn't buy a camera that doesn't have a viewfinder. Furthermore, I wouldn't buy a camera that has an electronic viewfinder. I can't imagine ever using a camera that doesn't have an optical viewfinder

Comment: Rather than asking whether it is essential, consider rephrasing to as about the pros and cons and about the situations where it is important and situations where it is less so. That will get better results, rather than a series or answers where some people say that it's vital and others say it's a waste.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the viewfinder absolutely essential in the Point and shoot segment?

It might depend on who you ask. To the vast majority of buyers of such cameras it must not be essential because pretty much all current compacts on the market do not have a viewfinder.

As far as your purchase is concerned the question should be, "Is the viewfinder absolutely essential *to me?*"

Answer (score 0):

For me, yes. For someone else, the answer may be different. The reason it is yes for me is that bringing the camera to my eye allows easier framing and easier framing correlates with better images.

One way to measure the importance of a veiwfinder for someone is looking at their pattern of usage regarding their cell phone camera. Someone who takes a lot of pictures similar to those they intend to produce with a dedicated camera probably will find a view-finder less essential (whether their photographs would improve is another matter). On the other hand, low cell phone camera use combined with a desire for a view-finder might mean that a view finder is 'necessary' for that person.

Answer (score -1):

Of course not. It is just an advantage if you have a viewfinder for point and shoot camera. Some intermediary experienced Photographers opt for them due its portability and other reasons and their love on Sony :) . But some cameras have electronic viewfinder which consumers more battery power which is useless.